# Error in installing msi installer on Windows 2000 that is created in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: installation, windows-installer, windows-2000

I have created a setup project which contains a windows service and a win forms application. I used the following configurations for preparing setup:

- Visual Studio 2010 on Windows XP
- .NET Framework 2.0
- Setup is created for x86 architecture.

When I tested this setup file it completed installation successfully. But since the customer has windows 2000 server, it needs to be installed on windows 2000 server operating system. However I get an error while installing to windows 2000 server. The log that indicates error is as follows:

MSI (s) (4C:68) [11:51:19:739]: Invoking remote custom action. DLL: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\MSI2E3.tmp, Entrypoint: ManagedInstall
MSI (s) (4C:44) [11:51:19:739]: Generating random cookie.
MSI (s) (4C:44) [11:51:19:755]: Created Custom Action Server with PID 348 (0x15C).
MSI (s) (4C:E8) [11:51:19:770]: Running as a service.
MSI (s) (4C:2C) [11:51:19:770]: Hello, I'm your 32bit Elevated custom action server.
Action ended 11:51:19: InstallExecute. Return value 3.

After that point rollback operation starts.

My first question:

I'm testing this in a virtual machine. I installed .NET Framework 2.0 on that operating system. May the problem arise because I'm using virtual machine? (Administrative problems maybe)

Second question:

If that's not the real cause what may be possible causes and solutions to solve this problem?

Comment: There should be a couple more lines of log above the snippet you posted which contain more information about the failing action. Can you please post them?

Comment: They were irrelevant for giving information about the error. So I didn't add them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to downgrade my project to Visual Studio 2008. I created the setup and finally it worked. I think this is a problem in Visual Studio 2010.